# Merge multiple PDFs to specific pages of single PDF based on PDF titles with PyPDF2

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I have a folder of PDFs that I'm currently merging using PyPDF2.

```
merger = PdfFileMerger()
for file in os.listdir('****'):
        if file.endswith(".pdf"):
            merger.append('****'+file)
merger.write('****' + str(dt.date.today()) + '.pdf')
merger.close()
```

The files contain graphs and the titles are very specific. What I would like to be able to do is:

Based on string in title, merge multiple PDFs to the same page of the new PDF (preferably split into two columns) - I know this isn't correct syntax but something like:

```
if 'dogs' in file: 
    merger.write(...,page=1,cols=2) 
elif 'cats' in file: 
    merger.write(...,page=2,cols=2)
```

Not sure if this is possible, have looked at other answers and read through the documentation but can't figure it out. Would also like to be able to have a fair amount of graphs (I guess up to 6?) on a single page.

Answer (score 0):

If the PDF titles are located in the same location in the file consistently, then you could do a `extractText()` function. Retrieve the title text in each pdf file. Then do your comparison analysis.

Comment: I probably didn't explain well enough.
I want all PDF's with 'dogs' in the title to be written to the same page in the merged PDF, all PDF's with 'cats' in the title to be written to the same page, etc etc. 'in' file works fine for parsing, I don't know how to merge and write to specific pages

Comment: Take each file that matches 'dogs' in the title and pass that pdf to a list  'dogsList' then pass the list of dog pdfs to the merger function.

Comment: Yes I'm not having a problem doing that necessarily, moreso getting it to go to the same PAGE since it writes each PDF to a separate page.